# Bonds and Force of Interest

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Studying for FM/2 and ran into this problem dealing with bonds;

A 1,000 par value 3 year bond with annual coupons of 50 for the first year, 70 for the second year, and 90 for the third year is bought to yield a force of interest

$$\delta_t=\frac{2t-1}{2(t^2-t+1)}, t\ge0.$$

Calculate the price of the bond.

So, $\delta_1=\frac{1}{2}, \delta_2=\frac{1}{2},$ and $\delta_3=\frac{5}{14}.$ And now, where do I go from here?

Comment: Force of interest is instantaneous.  If you want to discount back 1 year, it's not just the value of the force of interest at time 1, it has to do with the value of the force over the entire year.  In many problems, it's constant so you don't have to worry about it, but here it varies.

Comment: @Christoper: may I ask what book(s) are you using to get prepared for the FM/2 exam?

Comment: I have two.  I am using Finan's FM/2 because I he dumbs down the first sample problems so you get used to working with the particular machinery and then he moves into more difficult problems and old SOA/CAS exam problems.  I also have Broverman because he has great examples and explanations as well as sample exam problems, but Broverman has entire worked solutions to both problem sets and sample exams.  I did this for P/1 and passed with a 7 on my first try, so I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd approach it. The price of the bond is just the present value of the coupon payments and redemption value.
But note that $$\delta_t = \frac{2t-1}{2(t^2-t+1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(2t-1)}{t^2-t+1}.$$ This tells us that the accumulation function, $a(t)$, is given by $$ a(t)=(t^2-t+1)^{1/2}$$ because $$\delta_t = \frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}.$$ Now the coupon payments are as follows: $50$ at time $t=1$, $70$ at time $t=2$, $90$ at time $t=3$ and the redemption value(= par value because bond is redeemed at par) of $1000$ at time $t=3$. Hence $$PV = \frac{50}{a(1)}+\frac{70}{a(2)}+\frac{90}{a(3)} + \frac{1000}{a(3)}.$$

Comment: Ah, again @Nana you come with the good stuff!!  I forgot that $\delta_t=\frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}$